C11 memory model: Ensure that data is written between two atomics
I have two atomic ints and some other data. The ordering of the code execution should exactly be like this:

Write first atomic int
Write some data
Write second atomic int

Step 2 shall never be reordered (e.g. to before step 1).
Is the following code correct? If not, why not?
_Atomic uint32_t begin_id;
_Atomic uint32_t end_id;
int some_other_data = 0;

void bla()
{
    const uint32_t id = ...;
    atomic_store_explicit(&begin_id, id, memory_order_release);

    // ...writing some other data...
    some_other_data = f(x);

    atomic_store_explicit(&end_id, id, memory_order_release);
}

I'm not sure about the memory orderings.
Thanks
--- edit ---
Finally I changed to code to implement a seqlock (https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/include/linux/seqlock.h). The main difference is that I don't use a loop when reading (so only trying once) and that I use atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_acquire) to ensure the data is only written after the sequence is increased the first time. Also no spinlock is needed.

Relevant https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/memory_order

The second store should definitely be a memory_order_release, but for the first one I'm not sure, because there I want to enforce that no write after the atomic operation can be reordered before the atomic operation. memory_order_seq_cst should definitely do it, but I'd like to go for the cheapest sufficient option.

The second one is correct, the first one is not. There is no memory order that prevents other writes from being reordered before this write. It isn't clear how you would use one if it existed. You can prevent reordering of other memory operations before this read, or after this write, or both, but not before this write or after this read.

Okay, so I guess the only way is a memory barrier? E.g. __sync_synchronize()? Or do you know if there's some way to tell gcc not to do that? I don't care about portability etc:)

Atomic operations are primarily about the visibility of one thread's writes to other threads.  That is, about threads' perception of operation order, not directly about the actual order of operations.  If you want to prevent the compiler reordering operations within a single thread then volatile is a better tool for the job.

The final goal is actually some cheap synchronization which is allowed to fail: The reader thread will first read "end_id" and then "begin_id". If both are identical it will read "some_other_data" and then it will read again "begin_id" to check if it's still the same. In practice "some_other_data" is a much larger struct. If any of the checks failed, the program will continue doing other things.

You read both ids and find them identical, start reading some_other_data, then the writer thread starts the next round of modifications before you are done reading, and messes you up.

After reading some_other_data, the reader checks again begin_id. Only if it's still unchanged, it will accept the received data.

This way you have a good chance to never be able to read anything because the writer messes you up faster than you can finish reading.

In my case it's not an issue. The writer does not write too often plus the reader will only try to read it after the writer finished. The only edge-case is that the writer writes again new data, but that's very rare.

Also, writing data in one thread and reading it in another is UB territory (you theoretically may end up in a fully invalid state rather than with simply invalid data). Why not just use a normal spin lock?

That you need to think so hard about this scheme makes it a bad idea.  It will be easy for you or your successor to get it wrong or break it, and difficult to recognize that that has happened.  On most platforms, uncontested mutex acquisitions are cheap, so I would recommend just protecting the data with a mutex until and unless that proves to have inadequate performance.

If a mutex is too slow, then a better alternative would be to make the data to be read atomic themselves.  Use an _Atomic structure if there are multiple items.  You should be able to read and write that structure (whole) with memory_order_relaxed if you don't need to order that with respect to other objects.  Or you could write with memory_order_release and read with memory_order_acquire if you do need ordering with respect to operations on other parts of memory.

Unfortunately, mutex is way too expensive. Also _Atomic for larger structs will generate very inefficient code, so that is also no option (even gcc warns: large atomic operation may incur significant performance penalty).

Then the best you can do is something platform-specific.  Your approach allows data races, and the program's behavior is undefined if one occurs.  Your idea seems to be that you'll check after reading for the possibility of a race having occurred, and reject the data if one might have happened.  That is not a valid approach as far as the language spec is concerned.  Undefined behavior applies to the whole run of the whole program.

But you could conceivably restructure things to work around that.  I'm thinking of a variation on double-buffering.  You maintain two (or more) storage areas for the data, accessed indirectly via a shared, atomic pointer.  The writer updates the pointer to point to the latest data (memory_order_release) when it finishes writing.  The reader reads the pointer (memory_order_acquire) to find out which data to read, and it has these to itself unless reading takes longer than a full delay + write cycle. [...]

You can increase the time available for reading by increasing the storage for the data.  You can implement an atomic spinlock for a final failsafe to avoid misbehavior in the event that timing gets way out of whack, which is extremely unlikely if writes are as infrequent as you say.  Indeed, this approach would be viable for timing scenarios considerably more challenging than you represent yorus to be.

Locks are no option and I don't want to risk that the reader ever gets invalid data. The solution with pointers is okay, but given the reader could get inconsistent data, it's unfortunately not a possibility:/. However, it's okay to have a platform-specific solution.

Expanding on my comments, your scheme appears to be to

reduce the likelihood of a data race on the front end, then
check after reading whether there is a possibility that a data race occurred.

But this does not protect you from undefined behavior as a result of data races.  Example:

the reader checks end_id and begin_id, finds that they match, and begins reading the non-atomic data

the writer updates begin_id, with this landing between the reader's first and second loads of begin_id, and begins updating the non-atomic data
There are now data races for all the items written by the writer and also read by the reader.  The program's behavior is undefined, and that is not limited to (say) which values are / were observed by the reader.

eventually, the reader checks begin_id again, but that's meaningless.  The behavior of this check is undefined.  The behavior of any conditional branching based on the result is undefined.  All of this is true even with memory_order_seq_cst.


That is, your scheme does not work, in the sense that it does not prevent data races, and that if a data race occurs then then the whole behavior of the whole program is undefined.  This is not merely academic.  In actual practice, clever compilers sometimes optimize in ways that rely on all bets being off in the event of UB.  For example, by ignoring your reader's second read of begin_id, on the basis that it could differ from the first only in the event that the program execution has UB.

Alternatives
Atomic spinlock and non-blocking locking
Since you seem to expect that it will be rare for reader and writer to conflict, you could consider implementing an atomic spinlock as a light(er)weight alternative to a mutex.  That might look something like this:
static atomic_flag spinlock = ATOMIC_FLAG_INIT;

/*
 * Spin until the spinlock is successfully acquired
 */
void spinlock_lock() {
    while (atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit(&spinlock, memory_order_acq_rel)) {
        /* empty */
    }
}

/*
 * Try once to acquire the spinlock.  Return 1 if successful or 0 if not.
 */
_Bool spinlock_trylock() {
    return !atomic_flag_test_and_set_explicit(&spinlock, memory_order_acq_rel);
}

/*
 * Unlock the spinlock
 */
void spinlock_unlock() {
    atomic_flag_clear_explicit(&spinlock, memory_order_release);
}

The reader could use spinlock_trylock() to attempt to acquire the lock, but avoid waiting to do so.  The writer would, presumably, use spinlock_lock() to wait for the reader to clear the critical region before writing.  Both would release the lock when no longer needed via spinlock_unlock().
The memory ordering associated with the locking operations would have the additional effect of preventing races for data read or written while the lock was held, and the reader's efficiency would be improved by allowing it to skip reading at all when the writer was in the process of updating the data.
Multiple buffering
If you need to avoid the writer blocking while the reader reads, then you can do so by double- (or triple- or quadruple- ...) buffering the the data.  Since there seem to be several items, you would define a structure type with a member for each one.  You would then set up an atomic pointer that the writer would keep updated to point at the last-written version of the data. Reader and writer could then access the data concurrently, each working with its own copy.  The writer would store the pointer with memory_order_release; the reader would load it with memory_order_acquire.
This is not enough by itself to avoid data races, but if you combine it with a spinlock (see above) associated with each copy of the data, then that will do it.  The advantage of this over a single spinlock, alone, is that you can minimize the chance that the writer will ever have to wait to acquire a lock, and reduce the time that it is likely to have to wait in the event that it ever has to do so.

Wow that's exactly the answer I planned to write.

Finally, I went for a sequence lock similar to https://github.com/spotify/linux/blob/master/include/linux/seqlock.h (except for that I don't care about the loop in the read part and that I use atomic_thread_fence to ensure memory ordering)

Also I dont use a spinlock.

@KevinMeier, I recognize the similarity of that approach to what you proposed -- it's basically the same, but with only one counter.  And it has much the same issues as yours relative to the C language.  It can perhaps be used successfully in the Linux kernel, for which it is intended, by virtue of the kernel's tight requirements on compiler, compilation environment, and execution environment, and its environment-specific provisions for the target execution environment.  That does not make it a good model for general-purpose use.

Yeah, possibly for general-purpose use it's not the best model, but it perfectly fits my requirements. So at least for me it's perfect:)
